# MissingRequiredArgument, но значение переменной заданно заранее

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Не могу понять суть ошибки, если я указал значение переменной заранее, ведь если ничего не указать, то должен отправиться эмбед с ошибкой, но вместо этого я вижу ошибку в интерпретаторе.
Ошибка полностью:

---

```py
Ignoring exception in command mute:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "E:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "E:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 789, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "E:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "E:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 542, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: user is a required argument that is missing.
```

Код команды:

```py
class mute(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(aliases = ['m'])
    @commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
    async def mute(self, ctx, user: discord.Member = None, time = None, *, reason = None):
        if user == None:
            emb=discord.Embed(title=":x: | Ошибка", description='Укажите участника, которого хотите замьютить.', color = discord.Colour.red())
            await ctx.reply(embed=error1)
        else:
            #...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в строке `await ctx.reply(embed=error1)` embed=error1, когда embed emb

```
class mute(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(aliases = ['m'])
    @commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
    async def mute(self, ctx, user: discord.Member = None, time = None, *, reason = None):
        if user == None:
            emb=discord.Embed(title=":x: | Ошибка", description='Укажите участника, которого хотите замьютить.', color = discord.Colour.red())
            await ctx.reply(embed=emb)
        else:
            #...
```